# Fixing type inference in HLists

Tags: haskell, hlist

I've been trying to get the some code to compile. It's meant to take a `HList`, extract out the strings and concatenate them together.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Lib
    ( y
    ) where

import Data.HList

data HConcat2 = HConcat2
instance ApplyAB HConcat2 (String, String) String where
  applyAB _ (a,b) = a ++ b
instance ApplyAB HConcat2 (Int, String) String where
  applyAB _ (_,a) = a

x :: HList '[Int, String, Int, String]
x = 3 .*. "Hello" .*. 4 .*. " World" .*. HNil

y :: String
y = hFoldr HConcat2 "Result: " x
```

Unfortunately, when I try to compile this it gives me

```
    No instance for (ApplyAB HConcat2 ([Char], [Char]) r2)
      arising from a use of ‘hFoldr’
    The type variable ‘r2’ is ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance ApplyAB HConcat2 (String, String) String
        -- Defined at src/Web/Rusalka/Condition.hs:274:10
    In the expression: hFoldr HConcat2 "Result: " x
    In an equation for ‘y’: y = hFoldr HConcat2 "Result: " x
```

How do I convince it to use the instances I've declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional dependency on the `ApplyAB` class, so when GHC tries to select an instance, the input types don't determine the result type.  In this case, this causes all the intermediate types in the `hFoldr` chain to become ambiguous, and GHC doesn't know which instances to select.

To solve this, you can use a trick, where you keep the result type completely general in the head of the instance, and use an equational `~` constraint to restrict it *after* GHC has selected the instance (only the head of an instance is used for selection).

If you do `:i ApplyAB` in GHCi, you will notice that several of the pre-defined instances use such equational constraints.

Using this (and adding `TypeFamilies`) makes your code work for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Lib
    ( y
    ) where

import Data.HList

data HConcat2 = HConcat2
instance s ~ String => ApplyAB HConcat2 (String, String) s where
  applyAB _ (a,b) = a ++ b
instance s ~ String => ApplyAB HConcat2 (Int, String) s where
  applyAB _ (_,a) = a

x :: HList '[Int, String, Int, String]
x = 3 .*. "Hello" .*. 4 .*. " World" .*. HNil

y :: String
y = hFoldr HConcat2 "Result: " x
```